# SQL Server: Find duplicate substrings in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of clients in SQL Server. I'm trying to find away to find duplicates in the email_address column, but I need to only consider part of the column data, so a substring. In practical terms I need to find duplicate domain names in the records.

I have used the following query to find exact duplicates (on the whole field), but how can I modify this to consider a substring?

```
SELECT a.email_address, b.dupeCount, a.client_id
FROM tblClient a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT email_address, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount
    FROM tblClient
    GROUP BY email_address
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b ON a.email_address = b.email_address
```

Many thanks!

Comment: How about your try something if you already suspect you need to use substring

Comment: just a side note, a pivot might be better performing for the data you're aiming to get.

Comment: Try joining on the matching substrings within the email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @contact table (
  [client_id] [int] identity(1, 1)
  , [email]   [sysname]
  );
insert into @contact
        ([email])
values      (N'joe@billy_bobs.com'),
        (N'sally@beauty.com'),
        (N'george@billy_bobs.com');
with [stripper]
 as (select [client_id]
            , [email]
            , substring([email]
                        , charindex(N'@', [email], 0) + 1
                        , len([email])) as [domain_name]
     from   @contact),
 [duplicate_finder]
 as (select [client_id]
            , [domain_name]
            , row_number()
                over (
                  partition by [domain_name]
                  order by [domain_name]) as [sequence]
     from   [stripper])
select from [duplicate_finder]
where  [sequence] > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not actually looking to delete the duplicate records, how can I get this to work without the delete part?

Comment: Adam, I updated to just a select statement to reflect your question.

Answer (score 0):

gee:

```
SELECT substr(email_address, 1, 2), count(*)
FROM tblClient 
group by 1
```

Comment: How would you modify this query to get all the rows associated with those unique substrings?